# How can I use Vue.js transitions without hard coding height?

Tags: css, vue.js, transition

I have a Vue app with an element that needs to expand and collapse with a button click. The effect needs to be animated to make it less jarring. I'm using the `<transition>` tag for this but it doesn't work unless I hard code the element's `height` property in the css. This won't work because the element contains dynamic data and will have varying heights.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <input type="button" value="Toggle" v-on:click="showIt = !showIt"/>
    <transition name="test-tran">
        <div class="test-block" v-show="showIt">
            <div v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showIt: false
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the corresponding css:

```
.test-block {
    /*
    adding a height makes the transition work but
    an accurate height can't be known ahead of time

    height: 100px;
    */
}

.test-tran-enter-active {
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.test-tran-leave-active {
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.test-tran-enter, .test-tran-leave-to
    height: 0;
}

.test-tran-leave, .test-tran-enter-to
    /*
    adding a height makes the transition work but
    an accurate height can't be known ahead of time

    height: 100px;
    */
}
```

Without the `height` property, the element shows and hides correctly but there is no animation. It just appears and disappears instantly.

How can I make the animation work without hard coding the height in the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is a pure css issue. In order transition to work height must be provided. You can solve it with a hacky way though.

See [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)